# XML Parsing issue with special characters

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to display “Administrative File & Express” but it is displaying as "Express". So I am unable to show anything that is before the “&”.

Comment: Have you tried putting a escape character before the &?  /&

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape chars like '&' in XML Parsing. See following link...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Now check XML you are receiving. if you are not receiving chars with escape sequence then you need to handle it in your code.....

Write here if you need further details.....